# How to export query results from multiple tables in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, export-to-excel, plsqldeveloper, multiple-tables

I am trying to export multiple tables to individual excel files (approximately 120 tables need to be exported) in PLSQL Developer. As of right now, I am running through this process

Run Query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

From the result window, click "Export Query Results" and save as .xlsx.

This is a lengthy process, and takes around a minute per table (lots of information!), I can't help but think there has to be an easier, more efficient way of doing this. I just can't find any information.

Comment: what database? your db must have an export command

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary, I'm two weeks into my first job and I'm honestly not sure how to figure that out. I've never worked with exporting tables in PL/SQL or SQL in general.

Comment: From the `plsqldeveloper` tag, can I take it this is Oracle and you are using the [PL/SQL Developer desktop IDE](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html)? If so, do you want 120 Excel files for your 120 tables, or would another format do?

Comment: yes, it is oracle. I have added a tag, in case that helps more people come across this. @WilliamRobertson, I have completed exporting the tables individually in the background of my work, but yes they would have to be excel files or at least a similar type of file.

Comment: PHP - Got PHPExcel and also access to an oracle database. Start writing a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of PL/SQL Developer you're working with but, in mine, i can run several selects ate the same time and several tabs will open as result.

When i right click the upper left corner of the results, it gives me an option to "Copy to Excel" and then "Copy all as xlsx".

This worked just fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

Use this command:

```
COPY persons TO '<file path>' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

example:

```
COPY persons TO 'C:\tmp\persons_db.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

ref: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/export-postgresql-table-to-csv-file/

Comment: I am getting an error saying that COPY is an invalid SQL statement.

Comment: It is not a postgress database